# List default arguments of a linux command

Tags: linux, command-line-arguments

I wanted to check what are default arguments for rsync.

Tried searching through man pages but did not found that.

Is there a way to get default arguments for linux command?

Comment: Do you mean defaults?  `rsync` doesn't have any default arguments - if it is run without arguments, you get the usage instructions.  For most linux commands, they either have no defaults and present usage instructions, or they have no defaults and will run without any - like `ls`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know what arguments are applied automatically if you just type "rsync" and hit ENTER? Generally, the default arguments will be listed in any MAN pages, and if they are not listed, it is likely there aren't any and you must specify all necessary arguments when running the command.

Comment: I suppose you could argue that the default argument for `rsync` is `--help` as that is what is run when no arguments are provided.

Comment: Yes you can say that --help is default. Sorry wanted new line. My bad is that I did not wrote any example. Will add an example of what I mean in a moment.

Comment: Guess I had some crazy idea that some commands add some of the arguments if nothing is provided by the user. I am aware of "alias", but though that some commands use some args by default even if none are supplied.

Comment: Sorry, @titus , Linux commands generally assume that you have memorized the flags you want, or that you are willing to dig around in the man pages for them.  When you want to do something more complicated, string them together using pipes or write a script that calls the command with the desired flags.

Comment: Some options do have defaults, of course, but the only way to know them is to read the man pages. Go to a man web page and search for 'default'.

Comment: Could you please adjust the question title and put 'rsync' there if it is specificslly about rsync semantic or change the question in a way you generally want to know how to list usage info for commands (something which is not very consistent with Unix besides man pages)

Comment: Yes some commands have default behavior, generally if it is a read command like `ls` it will list the current directory, if it is a destructive command like `rsync` it defaults to print help. There is no (general) mechanism to change that for all linux commands (it is not so uniform like in powershell). However you can overwrite commands with shell functions. There you can implement dynamic decisions "if no args do. that". Won't work with aliases, there you have to use separate aliases, which is however less confusing "mybackup= rsync ...."

Answer (score 3):

To make sure and cover all the bases I'm going to answer three different interpretations of your question.

### 1. rsync command by itself

To start, if you ran the `rsync` command by itself like this:

`linux-okrz:~> rsync`

The command has been designed to default to the same behavior as adding the `--help` flag.

### 2. default behavior when using rsync to copy

Next, if you were to run the command like this:

`linux-okrz:~> rsync one/file two/`

It would simply follow its default protocol. To clarify, it's not running any arguments. Arguments are for the purpose of changing the default behavior. So some examples of its default behavior would be:

- Non-verbose action - rsync will work silently.
- "quick check" algorithm that only looks for files that have changed in size or in last-modified time.
- Non-recursive. In other words, it won't sync into directories, you'd have to specify the files. (globbing would still work on files in the same directory e.g. "dir/*")
- Existing files in the destination directory retain their permissions
- New files pass on their permissions which can then be changed by the destinations directory's default ACL or umask.
- user and group ownership will change to the destination user invoked if rsync is occurring across hosts and the users are not the same.
- Will accept remote hosts in source or destination field

I hope it makes sense that these are not default arguments but rather its default behavior. You would then use arguments to change that default behavior as it suits your needs. The above was not a complete list by any means, but rather some of the default behaviors I saw listed in the man page.

### 3. command to use rsync with arguments by default

Lastly, if you wanted a command that ran rsync with specific arguments by default you could use an alias to accomplish that task. Example below:

```
colin@linux-okrz:~> alias myrsync='rsync -zahP'
colin@linux-okrz:~> myrsync one/ two/
sending incremental file list
./
file
          0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/2)
```

I think in your case you're probably asking about my second interpretation regarding the command's default behavior, but I figured I'd include these three for anyone else that might stumble upon the same question with one of the other meanings in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Please use following command. You can search "example" in man command.

man rsync

You can also refer following URL. You will get more information for rsync command.

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/rsync.htm

Comment: Another tip, you can type 'man rsync' in a search engine and click any of the results to get the same information only in an easier to use format.

Comment: Sorry I cannot accept the answer. Please check my comment ^ .